# Elimination of Arbitrary Constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question: $y = \alpha x + \beta e^{4x}$. Eliminate the arbitrary constants, $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Solution:

Eq 1: $y = \alpha x + \beta e^{4x}$

Eq 2: $y' = \alpha + 4\beta e^{4x}$

Eq 3: $y'' = 16\beta e^{4x}$

However, when I try to make an equation to eliminate the arbitrary constants, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, I ended up isolating $\alpha$ and $\beta$ then substitute to the equations above, yet it does not make sense.

Also, I try to isolate $x$ on the first equation, yet $x = \frac{y - \beta e^{4x}}{\alpha}$ does not make sense either.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Draw $\beta$ from the third and eliminate $\alpha$ from the first and the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Write

$$ye^{-4x}=\alpha xe^{-4x}+\beta$$ and differentiate. This eliminates $\beta$, giving after simplification

$$y'-4y=\alpha(1-4x).$$

Then differentiate

$$\frac{y'-4y}{1-4x}=\alpha.$$

You only need to compute the numerator.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

$$y = \alpha x + \beta e^{4x}$$
$$\implies y'=\alpha+4\beta e^{4x}$$
$$\implies y''=16\beta e^{4x}$$

From this system you deduce $\beta$:

$$
\begin{cases}
y = \alpha x + \beta e^{4x} \\
 y'=\alpha+4\beta e^{4x} \\
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
y = \alpha x + \beta e^{4x} \\
 xy'=\alpha x+4x\beta e^{4x} \\
\end{cases}
$$
$$\implies y-xy'=\beta e^{4x}(1-4x)$$
$$\beta e^{4x}=\frac { y-xy'}{(1-4x)}$$
We had:
$$ y''=16\beta e^{4x}$$
Therefore:
$$\implies y''=16\frac { y-xy'}{(1-4x)}$$
$$(1-4x) y''+16xy' -16y=0$$